# Overlay bar graphs in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay bar graphs in `ggplot2`

My current code produces a bar plot but they are stacked on top of each other. I dont want this, I would like them overlaid so I can see the differences in each bar height.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)


x = c("Band 1", "Band 2", "Band 3")
y1 = c("1","2","3")
y2 = c("2","3","4")

to_plot <- data.frame(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2)
melted<-melt(to_plot, id="x")

print(ggplot(melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=.3))
```

Stacked output:

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding `position = "identity"` to your `geom_bar` call. You'll note from `?geom_bar` that the default position is `stack` which is the behavior you're seeing here.

When I do that, I get:

```
print(ggplot(melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha=.3))
```

[image]

And, as noted below, probably `position = "dodge"` would be a nicer alternative:

[image]

Comment: maybe position should be `"dodge"`?

Comment: @Seth Yes, that would probably be preferable (and would make the legend more understandable), I was just going with what the OP seemed to want.

Comment: So simple, cant believe i missed that, thanks